# No symbols rendered on GeoServer - 500 Server Error

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to test out my GeoServer instance that is running live on a TomCat server. Everything works fine, I did all the necessary steps to avoid problems with CORS - URI has been set up, all the example layers are there.

However, layer preview is not working at all. If I go to check out the styles, or if I test the example layers with OpenLayers, nothing comes up. When I go to create a style, all I see is a blank image where the example symbol should be ( like one of those corrupt images when the page does not load properly).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was.

Usually, everything starts from CORS configuration, meaning one needs to set up the webspace URI (In the global settings)

However, if that doesn`t work, and if the issue still persist (by issue I mean opening the OpenLayers preview only to see nothing), then the issue is with the Java installation. Please check the Java version and install the latest one. Then reinstall GeoServer.